# GitHub - how to get repo commit updates in the dashboard feed without issues/PRs notifications?

Tags: github

If I want to see commit updates of a certain repo in my GitHub [Dashboard](https://help.github.com/articles/about-your-personal-dashboard/) feed, I can 'follow' the repo.

But then I will also get email updates and Github notifications of issues and pull requests (which I don't want to be notified of).

Is there a way to subscribe to the commits feed updates without getting issues/PRs notifications?